# How to structure database for inventory of unlike items

Tags: database-design, inventory

I'm creating a database for an inventory of unlike items. For example, I may have automobiles, engines, and carburetors.

For each type of item, there are unique attributes, and some are uniquely-identified (AKA "serialized") items, and some are not.

Attributes could be, for example:

**Automobiles**

- serialNumber
- color
- doorCount
- transmissionType

**Engines**

- serialNumber
- cylinderCount
- displacement

**Carburetors** (unserialized)

- barrelCount
- manufacturer

Of course, I need to be able to determine how many of each type of item I have. I don't want to create a table for each type, since the item type will increase as I begin to carry transmissions, tires, radios, steering wheels, etc.

One method I've seen to deal with such a heterogeneous inventory is to have an `item` table, but to also have an `attribute` table. It looks like this:

**Table: *item* **

- (key) itemType (linked to a table of itemTypes that include "automobile", "engine", etc.
- (key) serialNumber
- (other fields common to all itemTypes)

**Table: *attribute* **

- (key) attributeType (linked to a table of attributeTypes such as "color", etc.)
- (key) itemType (linked to itemType in *item*)
- (key) serialNumber (linked to serialNumber in *item*)
- attributeValue (if attributeType is "color", this might be "red", "blue", etc.)

One challenge this presents is dealing with non-serialized items. While it is easy with this structure to determine that I have 35 engines, how would I represent that I have 52 carburetors? I don't want to have to serialize them.

This, of course, is not the only way to structure a database for heterogeneous inventory. What have you used, or what other ideas do you have?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this table setup:

Item types table:

- id PRIMARY autoindex
- name

Items table:

- id PRIMARY autoindex
- type (fkey to item types)

Attribute_types:

- id PRIMARY autoindex
- name

Values table:

- id PRIMARY autoindex
- item (fkey to items)
- type (fkey to attribute_types)
- value

So, if you wanted to store an engine, you'd add the type "Engine" to types table, then add an individual item.  Then, you could add values for "serial", and other properties.

If you wanted to store your carburetors, you could add a type called Carburetors, then make a single instance of it, and then make "value" entry for "quantity" = 53.

Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: Thanks. This is much like I posted, but I like your idea of making `serialNumber` just another attribute. The one thing I don't like is storing `quantity` as an attribute, because that quantity may be at various locations/bins. I suppose that just brings into play how I'm going to address inventory locations. Thanks, though, this is helpful.

Comment: Also, the problem persists of representing that I have 8 four-barrel Edelbrock carbs , 35 double-barrel Schebler carbs, and 10 double-barrel Edelbrock carbs. The attribute-centric approach here pretty much deems that there has to be one `item` record for each piece of inventory.

Comment: Well, maybe there needs to be an itemType for double-barrel Edelbrock carbs, and one for each other type. Basically, itemType will hold all the part numbers or SKUs.